# Atom Xdebug not working with PHPUnit CLI on Windows

Tags: php, debugging, phpunit, atom-editor, xdebug

I'm using PHPUnit 7.2 with Atom 1.27.2 via cli and now I'm trying to make it work with it's Xdebug, php-debug package.

I'm on Windows 7 and PHPUnit was installed using Composer.

The thing is that the program hits the breakpoints, but it seems that it's not answering the the debugger commands, it's just stuck, there is no stack trace, no context variables, but it continues when I click the detach the debugger.

I've tried many ways to make it work using `set XDEBUG_CONFIG=idekey=xdebug-atom` before executing the script, checking it later with set... didn't work.

Tried setting `xdebug.idekey="xdebug-atom"` in the php.ini file, same thing.

Tried using this config file:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="api test">
      <directory>test</directory> 
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <php>
    <cookie name="XDEBUG_SESSION" value="xdebug-atom"/>
    <ini name="xdebug.profiler_enable" value="on"/>
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

same thing.

Tried with this xml:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="api test">
      <directory>test</directory> 
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <php>
    <ini name="xdebug.idekey" value="xdebug-atom"/>
    <ini name="xdebug.profiler_enable" value="on"/>
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

same thing again.

What other options is there available? Is there any other options or does php-debug atom package does not support PHPUnit via CLI?

**[EDIT]**

Debugging other scripts directly from the browser with Atom php-debug works normal, it just isn't working with PHPUnit.

**[EDIT]**

Using Notepad's 7.5.6 dbgp debugger plugin works, I just wanted to not use both editors.

Comment: Quite possible that PHPUnit runs tests in separate processes ... so Xdebug creates separate session for each of them .. and your Atom may simply not support such scenario.

Comment: possible, that's why I'm coming back to sublime for editing + notepad++ for xdebug as sublime xdebug is somehow bugged for me

Comment: PhpStorm? It supports simultaneous debug sessions (by default it set to just 1 though)

Comment: I wanted, but PhpStorm is not an option